# Correct way to handle asynchronous call & return in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I’m working on an Ionic 4 project. This is quite new for me to work in Javascript / Typescript and i’m having a hard time to understand how to use properly async / await / promise and all that stuff.

What i have :

On a page of my app (Let’s call it tab1.page.ts ) I have a function that call a function of my service :

```js
Get_Sim_Agents() {
       this.simConfig.Get_Sim_Agents();
    }
```

On my service page, here is the function : (a basic http get function) :

```js
/**
     * Fetch the datas in order to populate the app
     * */
    Get_Sim_Agents(){

        this.http.get(
            "http://" +
            this.ip_address +
            ":" +
            this.port +
            "/get_datas"
        ).subscribe(response => {

            var data = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);

            try {
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                // here i do stuff with the retrieved data
                });

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

And everything is working. But i would like my service function to return the data as a string when the data is retrieved & treated. I’m having a hard time finding the correct syntax.
Here is what i tryed :

On my service :

```js
/**
     * Fetch the Sim_Agents from the Simulation_orchestrator in order to populate the app
     * */
    async Get_Sim_Agents() : Promise<string>{

        this.http.get(
            "http://" +
            this.simulation_orchestrator_ip_address +
            ":" +
            this.simulation_orchestrator_port +
            "/get_sim_agents"
        ).subscribe(response => {

            var data = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);

            // here i do some stuff about the data

            return JSON.parse(data);
            });

        return 'test';
    }
```

On my page :

```js
Get_Sim_Agents() {
        this.simConfig.Get_Sim_Agents().then((result) => {console.log(result)});
    }
```

With this code my function called on my page return ‘test’ right away. I would like it to wait until the http get return the server response. I tryed several different syntax but couldn’t achieved what i want :confused:

To be clear:

What i'm looking for is a way to do this :

1/ The page call the service function
2/ the service make the request, and got a reply
3/ the service do stuff (populating the app with the datas per example)
4/ then it send a string back to the page , like “job is done”

But all i could find is solution that directly send the response from the service to the page, without any pre-treatment from the service

Comment: Try `await this.http.get()`;  You aren't telling the `async` function to wait until it has data.

Comment: No, the problem is that he's returning a string at the end of the function, instead of a Promise.

Comment: What is `this.http`, what does `.get()` return? Find a http library that returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't work because `Get_Sim_Agents` doesn't return a promise, but a string. Yes, you are making asynchronous calls inside it, but you still return a string.

Do this:

```js
/**
     * Fetch the Sim_Agents from the Simulation_orchestrator in order to populate the app
     * */
    async Get_Sim_Agents() : Promise<string>{

        return this.http.get(
            "http://" +
            this.simulation_orchestrator_ip_address +
            ":" +
            this.simulation_orchestrator_port +
            "/get_sim_agents"
        ).toPromise().then(response => {

            var data = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);

            // here i do some stuff about the data

            return JSON.parse(data);
        });
    }
```

Of course, depending on the version or RxJS, you need to make sure that `toPromise` is available.

And by the way, why are you stringifying the response and then parsing it?

Comment: "Of course, depending on the version or RxJS, you need to make sure that toPromise is available." Can you point me how to do that ? As it's curently sending a TS error saying that toPromise() does not exist

Comment: @Oscar are you sure `subscribe()` returns anything? I think you meant to use `map` or something.

Comment: Yes, @Bergi, you are right. I didn't realise he was subscribing to the observable instead of mapping it. I changed the code a bit, now it should work.